# Oracle Select From primary key column return null value?

Tags: oracle

I have one view created from the query. This query retrieves data from 2 tables joined together. One of them uses the primary key to inner join. But the data returned null results on the primary key. What is the problem here?

```
CREATE TABLE orderinfo
(
    orderid   VARCHAR2 (20),
    qtty      NUMBER (20, 0),
    price     NUMBER (20, 0)
)
/

ALTER TABLE orderinfo ADD CONSTRAINT orderinfo_pk PRIMARY KEY (orderid)
/
INSERT INTO orderinfo (orderid, qtty, price)
  VALUES   ('OD00001', 1000, 15000);

INSERT INTO orderinfo (orderid, qtty, price)
  VALUES   ('OD00002', 2000, 15000);

INSERT INTO orderinfo (orderid, qtty, price)
  VALUES   ('OD00003', 3000, 15000);

INSERT INTO orderinfo (orderid, qtty, price)
  VALUES   ('OD00004', 4000, 15000);

COMMIT
/

create table ordersend
(
    orderid varchar2(20),
    orderstatus varchar2(3)
)
ALTER TABLE ordersend ADD CONSTRAINT ordersend_pk PRIMARY KEY (orderid)
/

INSERT INTO ordersend (orderid, status)
  VALUES   ('OD00001', 'N');

INSERT INTO ordersend (orderid, status)
  VALUES   ('OD00002', 'N');

INSERT INTO ordersend (orderid, status)
  VALUES   ('OD00003', 'N');

INSERT INTO ordersend (orderid, status)
  VALUES   ('OD00004', 'N');

COMMIT
/

CREATE VIEW vw_ordersendstatus
AS
    SELECT   "orderid",
             "qtty",
             "price",
             "status"
      FROM   (SELECT   inf.orderid,
                       inf.qtty,
                       inf.price,
                       send.status
                FROM   orderinfo inf, ordersend send
               WHERE   inf.orderid = send.orderid AND status = 'N')
/
CREATE TABLE orderblock
(
    orderid   VARCHAR2 (20),
    qtty      NUMBER (20, 0),
    price     NUMBER (20, 0)
)
/
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_sendorder
IS
    CURSOR c_send
    IS
        SELECT   orderid orderid,
                 qtty,
                 price,
                 status
          FROM   vw_ordersendstatus;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN c_send
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO orderblock (orderid, qtty, price)
          VALUES   (i.orderid, i.qtty, i.price);

        UPDATE   ordersend
           SET   status = 'B'
         WHERE   orderid = i.orderid;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        RAISE '-1';
END;
```

Then
SELECT * FROM orderblock

That return null value on orderid field

Why???
Please Help

Comment: Your view cannot compile successfully because of your use of case-sensitive identifiers in the `select` when the subquery doesn't use those identifiers.  Your `insert` statements into `ordersend` fail because there is no `status` column.

Answer (score 0):

The create table for ordersend doesn't contain the STATUS column mentioned in the view.

In the view, you have used quoted, lower case column names. The quotes force Oracle to treat them as case-sensitive.

If you mix up quoted and unquoted column / variable names, you may get a situation where an unquoted orderid takes its value from an uppercase ORDERID or unquoted orderid rather than a quoted lower-case "orderid" you expected. Best to avoid quoted identifiers for columns, variables and tables.

Without a fully working script, it is hard to be certain

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gary,
In my question, I have a mistake AT view.
The correct is:

```
INSERT INTO ordersend (orderid, orderstatus)
  VALUES   ('OD00001', 'N');

INSERT INTO ordersend (orderid, orderstatus)
  VALUES   ('OD00002', 'N');

INSERT INTO ordersend (orderid, orderstatus)
  VALUES   ('OD00003', 'N');

INSERT INTO ordersend (orderid, orderstatus)
  VALUES   ('OD00004', 'N');

CREATE VIEW vw_ordersendstatus
AS
    SELECT   "ORDERID",
             "QTTY",
             "PRICE",
             "STATUS"
      FROM   (SELECT   inf.orderid,
                       inf.qtty,
                       inf.price,
                       send.orderstatus status
                FROM   orderinfo inf, ordersend send
               WHERE   inf.orderid = send.orderid AND orderstatus = 'N')
```